# GIT shows information on commit id which does not belongs to branch

Tags: git

I have been working on GIT for sometime and I've got a basic doubt

a)  I created three text files 'a.txt, b.txt and c.txt' on branch 'master', added and committed the files

b)  I created a new branch 'temp' from 'master' (Commit# 666a663)

c)  I amended file 'c.txt' from 'master', added and committed it (Commit# 5cbbf09)

```
ca18:TEST_GIT sathishkumark$ git branch
* master
  temp

ca18:TEST_GIT sathishkumark$ git log --pretty=oneline
5cbbf09cf619fa5462240b8afe3af4274e0d7dcf File revised
666a6634e938e7aa5e042e1b443ef817a98b8232 Initial version
```

Now, I switched over to branch 'temp' using 'git checkout temp'

When I type-in 'git show 5cbbf09' from branch 'temp' git displays the information about the commit id# 5cbbf09

***Question***

The question here is why 'git displays information' about '5cbbf09' when I am on branch 'temp'.

Commit ID# 5cbbf09 belongs to branch 'master' and NOT to branch 'temp'.

I expect git NOT to display info for the commit because the commit does NOT belongs to branch 'temp'

Please clarify

Are GIT commits NOT tagged to branches ?  (or)  In other words, what's the relationship between 'branches and commits'.

Comment: On the output you posted, the "*" indicates that you are on the master branch and not on temp when you called git log.

Comment: Yeah Output was posted just to show branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much to clarify here, you're asking about a specific commit, so GIT shows information about it. What does it matter what branch you're on? Your expectations are wrong in this case.

If you only want commits on your current branch, a simple `git log` with no parameters by default will give commits from the beginning of time to the tip of your branch only, with no other branches.

You can then filter using other flags, but giving a specific commit (or branch) will force GIT to show them, as per your direct request. If you don't want to see info about the commit, why are you referencing it? Basically you want a program that ignores you...

To answer your final question: **no**. The logic is reversed. In fact, branches are just 'pointers' to a commit, nothing more - Other versioning tools have different concept of branches, so this is a good point to notice early on. You can move this pointer around, but this won't affect commits in the general case. Note though a commit chain with no branch at the end is sort of like 'leaked memory', and git will clean it up if you get to that situation.

The log will behave differently though: if you `git log <branch>` than you will see a log up until the commit the branch is pointing to, regardless of your current branch, and not just the commit being pointed to.

The only thing other then the ID that can be associated (identity wise) with a specific commit, is a [tag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) (which is not a branch! rather, a naming of a commit, or an alias if you will), but that's all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I worked on few other SCM's hence I thought about it

Comment: @SathishKumar I see. If you have any specific thing you're trying I can add that to the post.

Comment: @SathishKumar Answered.